# The "AntlrClassGenerationTask" task was not found

Tags: visual-studio, antlr

in an Visual Studio 2010 project with an ANTLR grammar, I am getting the following error "The "AntlrClassGenerationTask" task was not found".

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the solution folder had in the name the characters "(2)", apparently this caused the ANTLR task to be not found (in other branches was working fine) and the task assembly was included in a folder inside the solution.

So after changing the folder name from "MySolution(2)" to "MySolution", the problem went away.

A bit weird since, there were no absolute references to solution folder, all used VS macros like $(ProjectDir)Antlr.